# подсчет популяции страны

Tags: javascript

Вот такое задание дали

> Given an array of countries with their population.   Calculate total
>
> population of all countries.
>
> ```
>  [
>   { name: 'Ukraine', population: 42 000 000},
>   { name: 'Belarus', population: 9 500 000},
>   { name: 'Moldova', population: 3 500 000},
>   { name: 'Switzerland', population: 8 400 000}   
>  ]
>
>  Total population = 42M + 9.5M + 3.5M + 8.4M = 63.4M
> ```

подскажите код, я только пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: Эээ, написать цикл?

Comment: я только начала учить, можно хотяб ссылочку на похожее задание. спасибо

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/ для начала неплохо бы основы языка выучить.

Comment: это тестовое задание чтоб взяли учиться у меня у день(

Comment: и чему вы научитесь если не знаете основ?

Answer (score 2):

> подскажите код, я только пытаюсь разобраться

Вот такой вариант кода.

```js
var ar = [
  { name: 'Ukraine', population: 42000000},
  { name: 'Belarus', population: 9500000},
  { name: 'Moldova', population: 3500000},
  { name: 'Switzerland', population: 8400000}   
 ]
 // Функция аккумулятор
 const reducer = (acc, cur) => acc + cur.population;
 // Вызов функции с начальным параметром 0
 console.log(ar.reduce(reducer,0));
```

[Метод reduce() доки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: функция аккумулятор?

Comment: reduce конечно хорошо, но думаю вам для начала нужно разобраться с [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) и [объектами](https://learn.javascript.ru/object)

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант

```js
(function() {
    
    var sum = 0;
    
    function sumPopulation(arr) {
    
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            console.log(arr[i].population);

            sum += arr[i].population / 1000000;
        }
        
        console.log(sum);
        return sum;

    }

    var arr = [{
            name: 'Ukraine',
            population: 42000000
        },
        {
            name: 'Belarus',
            population: 9500000
        },
        {
            name: 'Moldova',
            population: 3500000
        },
        {
            name: 'Switzerland',
            population: 8400000
        }
    ];
    
    sumPopulation(arr);
    
    var output = document.querySelector('.output');
      output.innerHTML = 'Total population = ' + sum + 'M';
    
})();
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```